# Setting up UDP socket connection Linux

Tags: networking, udp

I'm trying to make my application communicate with an application, [MAVProxy](http://ardupilot.github.io/MAVProxy/html/getting_started/starting.html), that sends packets to any other application listening to port `udp:127.0.0.1:14551`.
When my code (taken from [here](http://www.programminglogic.com/sockets-programming-in-c-using-udp-datagrams/)) is executing and MAVProxy is running and I run

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo -n udp port 14551
```

the output is

```
06:30:21.754884 IP 127.0.0.1.14551 > 127.0.0.1.14551: UDP, length 41
```

which means that my program listens to port `14551` and also sends packets to the same port. This is not what I want it to be. Following is my code:

```
int main(){
    int udpSocket, nBytes;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    socklen_t addr_size;  

    mavlink_msg_command_long_pack(mavlink_system.sysid, mavlink_system.compid, &msg, targetSysId,targetCompId, MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20);
    len = mavlink_msg_to_send_buffer(buf, &msg);

    udpSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(14551);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    // Enabling broadcasting
    int broadcastEnable = 1;
    setsocketopt(udpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcastEnable, sizeof(broadcastEnable));
    memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  
    bind(udpSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;

    while(1){
        sendto(udpSocket,buf,len,0,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr,addr_size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5501            0.0.0.0:*                           18485/arducopter
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34674           0.0.0.0:*                           18479/python    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14550           0.0.0.0:*                           18556/apmplanner2
udp   213504      0 0.0.0.0:14551           0.0.0.0:*                           18683/nav       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43852           0.0.0.0:*                           18479/python
```

These are the precesses communicating via UDP. Now, `18479/python` is expecting to communicate with `14550` and `14551`. `apmplanner2` can communicate successfully with `18478/python` but `nav` can't. `nav` just talks with itself.

How can I make my program get the port `14551` and communicate with whoever expecting to communicate on this port?

Comment: That tcpdump only shows the source and destination addresses. It does not show that _my program listens to port 14551_.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, thanks for your comment. What do you suggest so that my program has 14551 and it sends packets to whatever listens to this port? What is the right way to do that?

Comment: You need to use [UDP multicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast). With unicast only one listener can receive the datagram.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I've updated the code. Broadcasting should be enabled now but my program still just sends packets to itself on port `14551` while the other program is expecting to be connected to on `14551`. What do you think is missing?

Comment: You must broadcast on the network on which you want the hosts to receive the broadcast. You are using the loopback address as your address, so you are broadcasting to yourself. You need to use the address of the interface in the network on which you want to broadcast. Remember that broadcast interrupts _every_ host on that network, even if the host is not interested in listening to that UDP port. You probably want to use multicast to only interrupt the hosts listening for that multicast group.

Comment: @RonMaupin, thanks for your explanation. Please check my last update. The host I'd like to communicate with is on the same network as my program. This is my first time to deal with UDP sockets so please be patient and help me further. I'm working on this problem for more than two days now.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you are using loopback addresses, which do not route, and do not have networks or broadcast addresses. Anything sent to a broadcast address loops right back into the host. Your loopback addresses are individual host addresses; there is not network or broadcast address, or you can think of it as a loopback address is also the network and broadcast address, so sending a broadcast from a loopback address will only hit that same loopback address.

Comment: So how does apmplanner2 communicate with python successfully while it is in the same loopback? Isn't there anyway to solve this situation?